# Is Amazon S3 appropriate for serving videos?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm working on a website with a primary function of playing videos, typically one right after another.

**Would it be appropriate to store the MP4 & WebW files on Amazon S3, then accomplish playback using HTML5/Flash?**

Are there any speed repercussions with serving videos via Amazon S3? Or would I be better off serving the videos from the same Amazon EC2 server I'm using to run the site?

**Really I'm looking for Pros/Cons. Thank you.**

Comment: I am using s3 for very high read/write requests. How to handle it?? Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 8):

I cant imagine using Amazon for streaming. Honestly, their traffic costs are way too high for this kind of application.
Anyway, if you still want to use it, S3 doesnt seem to be good option, because it's cluster storage designed for e.g. archiving and not streaming, it has limitations of number of requests per second as well it's concurrency.
For streaming, you need the fastest possible storage, and any of the Amazon services is far away from that, definetely S3 and for EBS, it's not too fast either.
You can consider servers with SSD drives and normal bandwidth prices.
I have myself 10 streaming servers doing 100TB of traffic per day, each with 8x SSD drives and 10Gbps interface plus 64GB of RAM and 16 cores.

Comment: Plus the streaming offer from Amazon is not good either, it doesnt feature any decent security with encryption.

Comment: can you recommend a cdn provider better the n S3

Comment: Netflix use this, so I don't think it's a bad idea. Look at this [paper](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3662538304152045)

Comment: Ha ha ha. Netflix is huge, it has different deal with Amazon than other companies. It's super-expensive for such purpose UNTIL you are Netflix.

Answer (score 4):

I've used Amazons CloudFront to stream content in the past without too much issue (http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), but there are certainly faster methods out there.

However, I do believe it's a good place to start.

Comment: Although EC2 might allow you to get a bit more bang when it comes to features, etc, but the cost is much higher than using something like CloudFront.

Comment: Amazon traffic prices are ridiculous when it comes to streaming. E.g. on CheapVPS you have 1TB traffic and a server capable of streaming with e.g. EVO stream for about £14 per month. On amazon, same would cost you $120 at MINIMUM, this is around 10x higher price on the start!

Comment: ps. E.g. watching 1 hour of HD movie via amazon can cost e.g. $1, if you are using very low bitrate HD, or high bitrate SD. Now get 100 users, and you will have to pay $100 for 100 users. That's crazy man!

Answer (score 2):

[Amazon CloudFront supported streaming](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2009/12/15/announcing-cloudfront-streaming/) since December 2009:

> We’ve designed Amazon CloudFront to make streaming accessible for
>   anyone with media content. Streaming with Amazon CloudFront is
>   exceptionally easy: with only a few clicks on the AWS Management
>   Console or a simple API call, you’ll be able to stream your content
>   using a world-wide network of edge locations running Adobe’s Flash®
>   Media Server. And, like all AWS services, Amazon CloudFront streaming
>   requires no up-front commitments or long-term contracts. There are no
>   additional charges for streaming with Amazon CloudFront; you simply
>   pay normal rates for the data that you transfer using the service.

Recently [Amazon CloudFront introduced Live Smooth Streaming](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/04/01/amazon-cloudfront-announces-support-for-smooth-streaming/):

> We are excited to announce the launch of Live Smooth Streaming for
>   Amazon CloudFront. Smooth Streaming is a feature of Internet
>   Information Services (IIS) Media Services that enables adaptive
>   streaming of live media to Microsoft Silverlight clients. You can also
>   use this solution to deliver your live stream to Apple’s iOS devices
>   using the Apple HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) format. And you can benefit
>   from the scale and low-latency offered by Amazon CloudFront when
>   delivering your live Smooth Streams.

Comment: Man, get calculator and check how much does it cost to watch continuously 1Mbps stream 24/7. It's such a ripoff I am totally shocked that you are making advertizing of Bezos ridiculously prices services! It's not even useful for development, because you cant move it out of amazon, as it's their CDN. They are dozens of way much cheaper alternatives, amazon is not the only streaming provider, actually, it's the most expensive and most rubbish with least features in fact, check streaming monkeys etc.

Comment: @AndrewSmith: dude, get a calculator, your 1Mbps 24/7 is $300 a month for CloudFront.